# current_page? on nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

How can I detect with `current_page?` a nested resource?

Let me clarify: I have two controllers: `Manufacturers` and `Models`

```
#routes.rb

resources :manufacturers do
  resources :models, except: :index
end
```

If I try to detect the show page of manufacturers, all I have to do is this:

```
<% if current_page?(controller: 'manufacturers', action: 'show') %>
```

Everything works as expected. But if I try the same for the `Models` controller:

```
<% if current_page?(controller: 'models', action: 'show') %>
```

I get this error: `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"models"}`.

---

I end up doing a **workaround**:

```
<% if controller.controller_name == "models" && controller.action_name == "show" %>
```

but I would like to know how can I accomplish the same result with `current_page?` helper.

Hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the url you are trying to check this on?

Comment: @nikamanish for example: `http://localhost:3000/manufacturers/2/models/12`

Comment: If the manufacturer instance is available in your views file. Can you try `current_page?(controller: 'models', action: 'show', manufacturers_id: manufacturers.id)`.

Comment: @Mosaaleb that variable isn't available on that view :/

Comment: Try passing id of the model also in the current_page? method parameter - 

`<% if current_page?(controller: 'models', action: 'show', id: model.id ) %>`

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this on Rails 5.2 using standard nested resources, as suggested by the question. Do you want to share controller code and view code?

Answer (score 0):

When you have nested resources like this:

```rb
resources :manufacturers do
  resources :models, except: :index
end
```

Your route to models look like this:

`manufacturers/:manufacturer_id/models`

Therefore in this call the `manufacturer_id` is missing:

`current_page?(controller: 'models', action: 'show')`

I solved this by a custom helper:
`app/helpers/application_helper.rb`

```rb
module ApplicationHelper
  def page?(controller:, action:)
    controller_name == controller && action_name == action
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
current_page?(controller: 'manufacturer/models', action: 'show')
```

Comment: I think that would only work for namespaced controllers, not nested routes.

Comment: it worked for my groups/posts#show with routes like resources groups do; resources  posts; end

Comment: @DileepNandanam unfortunately it didn't work for me :/

Comment: @Proz1g make sure you are on the correct page manufacturers/:id/models/:id

Comment: I'm getting error @DileepNandanam. `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"manufacturers/models"}`